# Duplicated checkbox's that cannot have the same option that was selected on one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<select>` boxes with similar options at the beginning.

When the user selects the option *X* in `<select id="first">` the same option should be deleted from `<select id="second">` and vice versa.

I would prefer a solution in JavaScript without any additional framework like jQuery. I've got the following solution currently:

```
/* first  - the first check-box
   second - the second check-box */

$('#first').bind('change', function () {
    $('option:not(:selected)', this).clone().appendTo($('#second').empty());
});

$('#second').bind('change', function () {
    $('option:not(:selected)', this).clone().appendTo($('#first').empty());
});
```

However, I have the following problem: Say we have 10 options in both select box. After choosing one on `#first` i get 9 option in `#second`. If I choose one from the nine item in `#second` the first chosen item gets deleted in `#first` and I have only 8 items in `#first`. One can repeat this steps and end with a empty `<select>` and one with only one option.

I thought about kind of temp object that would save all the time the original options.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Don't remove or hide the element. Instead _disable_ it, using `.disabled = true`. Then you can simply enable all other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu should be able to show and hide the options as you need them so something like this:

```
$('#first').bind('change', function () {
        $("#second option").show();
        $("#second option[value='" + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') +"']").hide();
  });
```

and this is one of those things where jQuery is a lot easier to use that vanilla JavaScript if you wish to make it consistent across browsers

Comment: its seems doing the job, but hiding `<option>` elements is browser consistent? I use it as Hybrid App on HTML5 so I afraid it wont work on all devices.

Comment: @dima it's valid html5

Comment: It is? it's more jQuery thing then HTML5, not?

Comment: @Dima jQuery is just a wrapper around JS and CSS, so if there's no support in the underlying HTML/CSS model then there's no way to implement it in jQuery. jQuery abstracts away the difference between a number of html/css models at are therefor a lot easier to use when it comes to being cross browser compatible. Since this is accomplished using CSS in mordern browsers there will be support for it

Comment: You right. Is it possible to remove the `.find` and to write :  `$("#second option[value='" + $(this + 'option:selected').attr('value') + "']").hide();` ?

Comment: @Dima quickest way to find out is to try (the answer is no) and why would you want to anyways?

Comment: @Dima you will have to explain more than that. E.g. What error messages do you get in the dev console

Comment: Well in browser it works perfect but in Android `display:none` doesnt work for selectmenu on mobiles, and this is what the `.hide()` method actually do.